# Visualize polygons of shapefile in GeoServer with different colors for even and odd numbers of "id" field?

Tags: geoserver, symbology, sld

I have a polygon shapefile in GeoServer. I want to visualize the polygons with even ids in dark purple and odd ids in light purple.

What is the SLD that can do it?

Comment: What have you tried? What seems not to be working?

Comment: What is the best source for understanding SLD? any book website, online course?

Answer (score 0):

I asked it from Chat GPT. It gave me 3 or 4 times things with error.
Finally, it gave me something with only 1 error.
I found that "mod" function that Chat GPT suggested, does not exist in this list:

https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#filter-function-reference

I replaced mod function of Chat GPT with IEEERemainder. Now, the SLD works fine with no error.

```
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.0.0">
  <sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>NV301:20220503_ZoneRestriction</sld:Name>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>Even and Odd IDs</sld:Name>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>Even ID</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:Function name="IEEERemainder">
                <ogc:PropertyName>id</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
              <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#af8dc3</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>Odd ID</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:Function name="IEEERemainder">
                <ogc:PropertyName>id</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
              <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#e7d4e8</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```